# What is the difference between type-hinting a variable as an Iterable versus a Sequence?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

I don't understand the difference when hinting `Iterable` and `Sequence`.

What is the main difference between those two and when to use which?

I think `set` is an `Iterable` but not `Sequence`, are there any built-in data type that is `Sequence` but not `Iterable`?

```
def foo(baz: Sequence[float]):
  ...

# What is the difference?
def bar(baz: Iterable[float]):
  ...
```

Comment: Related, with a meaningful answer: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-an-iterable-and-a-sequence-in-Python

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The `Sequence` and `Iterable` abstract base classes (can also be used as type annotations) mostly* follow Python's definition of [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) and [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). To be specific:

- **Iterable** is any object that defines `__iter__` **or** `__getitem__`.
- **Sequence** is any object that defines `__getitem__` and `__len__`. By definition, any sequence is an iterable. The `Sequence` class also defines other methods such as `__contains__`, `__reversed__` that calls the two required methods.

Some examples:

- `list`, `tuple`, `str` are the most common sequences.
- Some built-in iterables are not sequences. For example, `reversed` returns a `reversed` object (or `list_reverseiterator` for lists) that cannot be subscripted.

---

* `Iterable` does not exactly conform to Python's definition of iterables — it only checks if the object defines `__iter__`, and does not work for objects that's only iterable via `__getitem__` (see [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?#collections-abstract-base-classes) for details). The gold standard of checking if an object is iterable is using the `iter` builtin.

Comment: *"Some built-in iterators are not sequences"* - I think **all** built-in iterators are not sequences. Or do you know one that is?

Comment: @joel Yes, that's possible, although they did use an iterator as an example. If they meant to talk about iterables, I'd say dictionaries or sets would be more prominent examples. (Now that I'm re-reading their answer, I see their paraphrased definition of "sequence" is actually wrong. Maybe that's why they didn't use dictionaries as an example.)

Comment: @KellyBundy An example would be `range`; `isinstance(range(5), collections.abc.Sequence)` returns True. `set` is not a sequence because it doesn't define `__getitem__`. `dict` is an interesting example because it does define both `__getitem__` and `__len__`, but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) explicitly mentioned that it's not a sequence, because its `__getitem__` takes arbitrary types instead of just `int`.

Comment: `range(5)` isn't an iterator. `iter(range(5))` is (it's a `range_iterator`), and `isinstance(iter(range(5)), collections.abc.Sequence)` as expected returns `False`.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for correcting me. I should change my answer to say _iterable_ instead of _iterator_.

Comment: • **Iterable** is any object that defines \_\_iter__ **only** (object of class with only \_\_getitem__ method is not Iterable instance). 
Details: [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=iterable#collections.abc.Iterable)

Comment: @C0oo1D The link you shared is the docs for `collections.abc.Iterable`, which is *not* the official definition for what an iterable is. In fact, that paragraph explicitly mentions that "it does not detect classes that iterate with the __getitem__() method."

Comment: @ZecongHu As I can see, the question was about `Iterable` (`typing.Iterable` or `collections.abc.Iterable`), not about iterating possibility. And `Iterable` is **not** defines `__getitem__`. Perhaps, the answer needs to be rephrased a bit - for example, mentioning that `iter()` builtin is the only way to detect iterating possibility through `__iter__` **or** `__getitem__`.

Comment: And about difference of Iterable and Sequence, i would send [to this table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?#collections-abstract-base-classes)

Comment: @C0oo1D Good point. I made an edit to the answer explaining the differences b/w `collections.abc.Iterable` and iterable as defined in the glossary, and added a reference to that table. Thanks for point this out!

Answer (score 17):

When writing a function/method with an `items` argument, I often prefer `Iterable` to `Sequence`.
Hereafter is why and I hope it will help understanding the difference.

Say `my_func_1` is:

```py
from typing import Iterable
def my_func_1(items: Iterable[int]) -> None:
    for item in items:
        ...
        if condition:
            break
    return
```

`Iterable` offers the maximum possibilities to the caller. Correct calls include:

```py
my_func_1((1, 2, 3)) # tuple is Sequence, Collection, Iterator
my_func_1([1, 2, 3]) # list is MutableSequence, Sequence, Collection, Iterator
my_func_1({1, 2, 3}) # set is Collection, Iterator
my_func_1(my_dict) # dict is Mapping, Collection, Iterator
my_func_1(my_dict.keys()) # dict.keys() is MappingKeys, Set, Collection, Iterator
my_func_1(range(10)) # range is Sequence, Collection, Iterator
my_func_1(x**2 for x in range(100)) # "strict' Iterator, i.e. neither a Collection nor a Sequence
...
```

... because all are`Iterable`.

The implicit message to a function caller is: transfer data "as-is", just don't transform it.

In case the caller doesn't have data as a `Sequence` (e.g. `tuple`, `list`) or as a non-`Sequence` `Collection` (e.g. `set`), and because the iteration breaks before `StopIteration`, it is also more performing if he provides an 'strict' `Iterator`.

However if the function algorithm (say `my_func_2`) requires more than one iteration, then `Iterable` will fail if the caller provides a 'strict' `Iterator` because the first iteration exhausts it. Hence use a `Collection`:

```py
from typing import Collection
def my_func_2(items: Collection[int]) -> None:
    for item in items:
        ...
    for item in items:
        ...
    return
```

If the function algorithm (`my_func_3)` has to access by index to specific items, then both `Iterable` and `Collection` will fail if the caller provides a set, a `Mapping` or a 'strict' `Iterator`.
Hence use a `Sequence`:

```py
from typing import Sequence
def my_func_3(items: Sequence[int]) -> None:
    return items[5]
```

Conclusion: The strategy is: "use the most generic type that the function can handle". Don't forget that all this is only about typing, to help a static type checker to report incorrect calls (e.g. using a `set` when a `Sequence` is required). Then it's the caller responsibility to transform data when necessary, such as:

```py
my_func_3(tuple(x**2 for x in range(100)))
```

Actually, all this is really about performance when scaling the length of items.
Always prefer `Iterator` when possible. Performance shall be handle as a daily task, not as a firemen task force.

In that direction, you will probably face the situation when a function only handles the empty use case and delegates the others, and you don't want to transform items into a `Collection` or a `Sequence`. Then do something like this:

```py
from more_itertools import spy
def my_func_4(items: Iterable[int]) -> None:
    (first, items) = spy(items)
    if not first: # i.e. items is empty
        ...
    else:
        my_func_1(items) # Here 'items' is always a 'strict' Iterator
    return
```

Comment: Great answer, This should be accepted.
it explains the theory and the application

Answer (score 3):

- **`Iterable`** is anything that, roughly said, can be iterated over (looped over using a `for` loop).
- **`Sequence`** is an iterable with some additional properties: You can get its size `len(sequence)`, you can access its elements by their position `sequence[n]` etc.

When adding type hints to your function, you should follow two basic rules:

1. Types of input arguments should be as general as possible.
2. Output type should be as specific as possible.

Look at these examples:

```py
from typing import Iterable, List

def foo(numbers: Iterable[int]) -> List[int]:
    digits = list()

    for number in numbers:
        if 0 <= number <= 9:
            digits.append(number)

    return digits
```

The function `foo` searches for single-digit numbers. If you used the more strict type hint `Sequence[int]` for the argument `numbers`, it would indicate to the user of the function that the non-sequence iterables such as `set` are not allowed. But they work perfectly fine! You want your function to support as wide range of inputs as possible (to make most users happy) so it makes no sense to add such restriction.

The output type `List[int]`, on the other hand, is very specific so users of the function can have detailed information about the output they get.

```py
from typing import Sequence

def bar(numbers: Sequence[int]) -> bool:
    sorted = True

    for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
        if numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]:
            sorted = False

    return sorted
```

The function `bar` checks if numbers are in ascending order. Here the more strict type hint `Sequence[int]` is required since the code uses some features of sequences that are not supported in all iterables. If you used the type hint `Iterable[int]` instead, the user then might have been tempted to input `set` as an argument and got surprised by an exception `TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing`.