# Mypy type compatible with list, tuple, range, and numpy.array?

Tags: python, mypy

The code

```
import numpy as np

def join(v:list, delim:str = ","):
    """ join the elements of v using the given delimiter """
    return delim.join(str(x) for x in v)

print(join([0,1,2,3]))
print(join((0,1,2,3)))
print(join(range(4)))
print(join(np.array(range(4))))
```

runs, but mypy only likes the first call to `join` and says

```
x.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "join" has incompatible type "Tuple[int, int, int, int]"; expected "List[Any]"  [arg-type]
x.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "join" has incompatible type "range"; expected "List[Any]"  [arg-type]
x.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "join" has incompatible type "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]"; expected "List[Any]"  [arg-type]
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a different type annotation for argument `v` that will fix these errors?

Comment: Maybe something like `Iterable`? (see [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable))

Comment: Thanks -- could you make the comment an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Iterable vs Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72157296/python-iterable-vs-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Iterable` from the typing module (see [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable))

Comment: Given the simplicity of the question, some note about `typing.Iterable` deprecation in favour of `collections.abc.Iterable` would be useful here, IMO.