# How to create the @iterator_cache decorator?

Tags: python, caching

**Question:** How to create the `iterator_cache` decorator ?

```py
@iterator_cache
def cheap_eval(numbers: Tuple[int]) -> Tuple[int]:
    print("cheap eval of {numbers}")
    return expensive_eval(numbers)

def expensive_eval(numbers: Tuple[int]) -> Tuple[int]:
    time.sleep(5 + len(numbers))  # Example of consuming time
    print(f"expensive eval of {numbers}")
    return tuple(numb**2 for numb in numbers)
```

**Description:** I have the `expensive_eval` function from a library and I need to call it many times.

I want to create the `cheap_eval` that uses cache and gives the same result as `expensive_eval` to reduce the total time.

The first idea I had was to use an auxiliar function `eval_one` with `@lru_cache`, but calling `expensive_eval` for each value is not good cause there's the 5-second constant term for each call of `expensive_eval`.

How can I create the decorator such it memorizes all the iterable inputs instead of the entire tuple?

A code with input and desired output is:

```py
# Input
print(cheap_eval([1, 2]))
print(cheap_eval([1, 3]))
print(cheap_eval([1, 2, 3]))

# Output without iterator_cache
# total time = 22 seconds
cheap eval of [1, 2]
expensive eval of [1, 2]
[1, 4]
cheap eval of [1, 3]
expensive eval of [1, 3]
[1, 9]
cheap eval of [1, 2, 3]
expensive eval of [1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 9]

# Output with iterator_cache
# total time = 13 seconds
cheap eval of [1, 2]
expensive eval of [1, 2]
[1, 4]
cheap eval of [1, 3]
expensive eval of [3]
[1, 9]
cheap eval of [1, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: there are some implicit assumptions here that you really need to make explicit for this to make sense. `expensive_eval` takes a `tuple` of `int` objects, and returns a `tuple` of the same size. for any `n` int in the `tuple`, that will always provide the same corresponding output, regardless of the order or position of the integer in the tuple, correct? So it is doing some referentially transparent mapping on each integer of the tuple?

Answer (score 0):

So, just separate out uncached inputs and call the expensive function on the unseen inputs. Use this to update the cache. Then use the cache to populate the output.

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

_cache = {}
def cheap_eval(numbers: Sequence[int]) -> list[int]:
    new = [n for n in numbers if n not in _cache]
    # take care of the case where there are no new inputs
    new_results = expensive_eval(new) if new else []

    for n, r in zip(new, new_results):
        _cache[n] = r

    return [_cache[n] for n in numbers]
```

Make sure to take care of the case where there are no new inputs that you don't pass an empty list to incur the 5 second overhead for no good reason.

You can abstract out the above logic into a decorator if you want. But this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

The given solution satisfies the request and can be also applied for types other than `tuple`.

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Any
import types

def iterator_cache(func):  # Should be sequence_cache
    uncastable = (types.GeneratorType, range)
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(keys: Sequence[Any]) -> Sequence[Any]:
        new_keys = (key for key in keys if key not in cache)
        if not isinstance(keys, uncastable):
            new_keys = keys.__class__(new_keys)
        number_new_keys = sum(1 for _ in new_keys)
        if number_new_keys:
            new_vals = func(new_keys)
            for key, val in zip(new_keys, new_vals):
                cache[key] = val
        values_generator = (cache[key] for key in keys)
        if not isinstance(keys, uncastable):
            values_generator = keys.__class__(values_generator)
        return values_generator
    return wrapper
```

But note the difference between `Iterable` and `Sequence` as mentioned in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72158086/8740854)

The most common python structures are `generator`, `tuple`, `list`, `range`, `set` and `dictionary`.

- Preserves order of input and output: `generator`, `tuple`, `list`, and `range`. `set` and `dictionary` don't respect the input order due to hash values of the output of `expensive_eval`
- Keeps the same input/output type: `generator`, `tuple`, `list`, `set`. Depending on the output values, `range` returns a generator, not a `range` type.

Note that we supposed that keys are hashable. If it's not, then a dictionary cannot be used to store the values.